# is there a translation for the below query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to select a string as we can do in sql like:

select 'true' from my_db where status='checked';

in mongo.
But i am only able to select the status column and unable to select a custom flag like 'true' using the query.
Can anyone please guide if there is a mongo translation for the above query

Answer (score 0):

The projection language is pretty flexible. Something like this?

```
db.collection.find({
  status: "checked"
},
{
  status: {
    $literal: "true"
  }
})
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mpUaNXKpLHS)